# Fix darkmode color in a mail

Tags: email, outlook, colors, background-color, darkmode

Here is my problem. I have to apply darkmode to one of my mails. In this mail some colors come out like flash green and flash orange but when I switch to darkmode this color darkens on outlook app and gmail app. I've indicated in my code that I wanted to keep the same color as the basic one.

Thanks in advance.

```html
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width:100%;border:0;border-spacing:0;">
                           <tr>
                              <th align="center" style="padding: 16px 0px 12px 0px;">
                                 <table role="presentation" class="twoColumn" style="text-align:center;font-size:0;width:100%;">
                                    <tr>
                                       <th class="column" align="left" style="width:100%;max-width:330px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;">
                                          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width:100%;">
                                             <tr>
                                                <th style="padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;">
                                                   <p style="margin:0;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:18px;">
                                                      <img src="https://mcusercontent.com/59a944801075db9a2b0e3413a/images/c8145a5c-35b0-aff6-a08e-17ada2542cce.jpg" width="260" alt="" style="display:block;width:260px;max-width:100%;height:auto;" />
                                                   </p>
                                                </th>
                                             </tr>
                                          </table>
                                       </th>
                                       <th class="column" align="right" style="width:100%;max-width:330px;display:inline-block ;vertical-align:middle;  mso-padding-right-alt: 30px;">
                                          <table role="presentation" style="width:100%;">
                                             <tr>
                                                <th style="padding:10px;font-size:16px;line-height:18px;text-align:left;">
                                                   <p class="darkText" style="margin-top:0;margin-bottom:14px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif; color: #313a42;font-weight: normal">Na een tijdje te hebben geworsteld met een slechte reputatie is<strong> rosé helemaal terug</strong> van weggeweest.</p>
                                                   <div class="buttonCenter"  style="text-align: right;">
                                                      <!--[if mso]>
                                                      <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:250px;color:#ffffff !important; text-decoration:none !important;" arcsize="100%" stroke="f" fillcolor="#FA5528">
                                                         <w:anchorlock/>
                                                         <center>
                                                            <![endif]-->
                                                            <p   style="margin:0;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;  text-align: center"> <a class="buttonOrangeColour" href="https://forms.office.com/e/P3eEN9XXNv" style="background-color:#FA5528 ; border-radius: 20px; -moz-border-radius: 20px; -webkit-border-radius: 20px; color:#ffffff !important; display:inline-block; font-family:'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px;font-weight:bold; line-height:40px; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; width:250px; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">INSERT TEXT HERE</a> </p>
                                                            <!--[if mso]>
                                                         </center>
                                                      </v:roundrect>
                                                      <![endif]-->
                                                   </div>
                                                </th>
                                             </tr>
                                          </table>
                                       </th>
                                    </tr>
                                 </table>
                              </th>
                           </tr>
                        </table>
```